# Ubuntu recognizes my USB but it does not let me access

Tags: usb, nautilus

*Hi, I have a problem with the USB memory that is not recognized in ubuntu, I will explain: the USB drive is a Kingston 8.0 GB, when I write the command lsusb ubuntu recognizes it, but it does not allow me to access the files. my version of ubuntu is 18.04 LTS and the usb memory is 2.0*

*What appears to me in lsusb*

```
miguel@miguelrd:~$ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0951:1665 Kingston Technology Digital DataTraveler SE9 64GB
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1bbb:0195 T & A Mobile Phones 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 03f0:0024 Hewlett-Packard KU-0316 Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

*according to* `lsbk`

`NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop1    7:1    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6350
loop2    7:2    0  34.6M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop3    7:3    0  29.5M  1 loop /snap/sublime-text/44
loop4    7:4    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop5    7:5    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop6    7:6    0  34.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop7    7:7    0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop8    7:8    0    91M  1 loop /snap/core/6405
loop9    7:9    0  34.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
loop10   7:10   0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop11   7:11   0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop12   7:12   0  91.1M  1 loop /snap/core/6259
loop13   7:13   0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop14   7:14   0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop15   7:15   0 140.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
loop16   7:16   0 140.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop17   7:17   0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
sda      8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0    50G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   1   7.2G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom`

*according to* `df -h`

`S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
udev             841M      0  841M   0% /dev
tmpfs            174M   1.8M  173M   2% /run
/dev/sda5         49G    20G   28G  42% /
tmpfs            870M    54M  816M   7% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5.0M   4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            870M      0  870M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0        13M    13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop1        91M    91M     0 100% /snap/core/6350
/dev/loop2        35M    35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop3        30M    30M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/44
/dev/loop4        15M    15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop5       3.8M   3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop6        35M    35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop7       141M   141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop8        91M    91M     0 100% /snap/core/6405
/dev/loop10       15M    15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop9        35M    35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
/dev/loop11       13M    13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop12       92M    92M     0 100% /snap/core/6259
/dev/loop13      2.3M   2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop14      2.4M   2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop15      141M   141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
/dev/loop16      141M   141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop17      3.8M   3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
tmpfs            174M    16K  174M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs            174M    68K  174M   1% /run/user/1000`

according to parted -l

```
Modelo: ATA WDC WD1600AAJS-0 (scsi)
Disco /dev/sda: 160GB
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512B/512B
Tabla de particiones: msdos
Indicadores de disco: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin    Tamaño  Tipo      Sistema de archivos  Banderas
 3      106GB   160GB  53.7GB  extended
 5      106GB   160GB  53.7GB  logical   ext4


Modelo: Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 (scsi)
Disco /dev/sdc: 7747MB
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512B/512B
Tabla de particiones: msdos
Indicadores de disco: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin  Tamaño  Tipo  Sistema de archivos  Banderas
```

*I clarify, I also enter the folder called / media / pendrive and absolutely nothing appears*

*image that does not appear in the file manager (nautilus)*

[image: Nautilus]

Comment: Hi Miguel, lsusb shows a 64 GB USB drive. Is that correct? What is the output of `lsblk` and `df -h`?

Comment: According to what it says when I put lsblk is this: `sdc      8:32   1   7.2G  0 disk`

Comment: Does the disk have any partitions? Is it formatted?

Comment: @Pilot6, good one. @Miguel What is the output of `parted -l`?

Comment: Partitions do not have and I do not remember well if it is formatted, and when I put `parted-l` nothing appears

Comment: I do not know why he does not recognize it to see files, but in lsusb if it appears

Comment: lsusb recognizes it as a device. This doesn't indicate whether or not the device has been formatted. lsblk only shows sdc not sdc1 like it shows with sda (sda3 and sda5) sdc1 not showing up might be an indication of the drive not being formatted. Would you run parted with elevated privileges please? `sudo parted -l` (make sure there is a space between parted and -l)

Comment: `Modelo: ATA WDC WD1600AAJS-0 (scsi)
Disco /dev/sda: 160GB
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512B/512B
Tabla de particiones: msdos
Indicadores de disco: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin    Tamaño  Tipo      Sistema de archivos  Banderas
 3      106GB   160GB  53.7GB  extended
 5      106GB   160GB  53.7GB  logical   ext4


Modelo: Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 (scsi)
Disco /dev/sdc: 7747MB
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512B/512B
Tabla de particiones: msdos
Indicadores de disco: 

Numero  Inicio  Fin  Tamaño  Tipo  Sistema de archivos  Banderas`

Comment: already add it to the publication sudo parted -l

Comment: Ok, according to parted there is a partition table but no partition. You should create a partition. You could use gparted to create an ext4 partition or fat32 if you would want to use it with Windows. I am assuming there are no files written on it since there is no partition. install gparted by running `sudo apt install gparted`

Comment: When I saw the devices in GPARTED my memory would tell me when I said: unassigned, I put it in ext4 format and I gave it to apply, however Ubuntu still does not let me access it, in the sense that I can not put files there.

Comment: @MiguelAngelMateo use "Disks" instead. IIRC it is installed by default. If you choose the EXT4 filesystem, you may need to change permissions on the drive (by using `chmod` or `nautilus` as root (use `pkexec nautilus` to run nautilus as root).